# MYSQL Prepared Statement not behaving

Tags: php, mysql

I'm stumped!!

I have a prepared statement with variables in it...

```
    DELIMITER $$

create procedure select_or_insert(
IN unit VARCHAR(255),
IN STKEY VARCHAR(255),
IN mark INT(2))
begin

IF EXISTS (select * from studentmarks where STKEY = STKEY and unitcode = unit) THEN
    UPDATE studentmarks SET unitmark = mark where unitcode = unit and STKEY = STKEY;
ELSE 
    INSERT INTO studentmarks (STKEY,unitcode,unitmark)
VALUES (STKEY,unit,mark);
END IF;

end
```

Calling it as...

```
    foreach ($_POST as $unit=>$mark){
if (!mysqli_query($con,"CALL select_or_insert('$unit','$STKEY','$mark')")) {
  die('Error: ' . mysqli_error($con));

}
}
```

What should happen (or what I intended happening) is...
Enter new records if they don't exist and Update them if they do.

The statement behaviour is:
It will create a new records when table is empty. It will update records when populated but only updates the existing records. It does not create new records when STKEY is changed. The variables seem to work as it will enter new records.

Is my syntax correct? Am I going about it the right way? Have I provided enough information?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: _'Am I going about it the right way?'_ - no. Set your `STKEY` column as unique in your table, then apply your update with `INSERT...ON DUPLICATE KEY...` ([Reference](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/insert-on-duplicate.html)). No need for a stored procedure and only one call to the database.

Comment: BTW - this: `where STKEY = STKEY` is always true, so every row will be updated if you use your query. One side should be the column name.

Comment: Thanks Hobo Sapiens, I did look into that method. My table has multiple entries for STKEY. ie.

Comment: Your BTW could be it. I have the column name and the variable the same name. Will try and get back

Comment: Create a unique compound index for `STKEY` and `unit_code` and use the `INSERT...ON DUPLICATE` method.

Comment: Hobo Sapien - well done. Works a treat, thank you very much.

Comment: Thanks again, I will try try the ON DUPLICATE as I have read it is a better method.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to [Hobo Sapiens](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1864610/hobo-sapiens) suggestion regarding variable and column name the same, it is solved. I changed the prepared statement STKEY variable to STUKEY and it all behaves just as I expected.